# GoogleFormのプルダウンをseleniumで選択することができません

Tags: python, selenium

複数プルダウンが存在するGoogle Formの入力をselenium(Pythonを使用)で自動入力を行おうとしたところ、
こちらの方法を使って
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49854786/handling-drop-down-for-google-form-using-selenium
一つ目のプルダウンは選択できたのですが二つ目以降が選択できません。
コードとしては以下のようになります。

```
self.webElementClickOverlay(buttonInfo)
time.sleep(3)
options=self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("exportSelectPopup")
contents = options.find_elements_by_tag_name('content')
[i.click() for i in contents if i.text == target]
```

`buttonInfo` はプルダウンをクリックするときのXPath
`target` は選択したい文言になります

現象としては１回目の場合は `options`の中にプルダウンの選択肢の内容が入っておりループ処理がうごくのですが２回目以降は`options`の中にプルダウンの選択肢が入っていない状態になります。

対応方法をご存知の方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか？

追記
具体的にどういうGoogle Formかを追記しました
以下のGoogle Formのようにプルダウンが複数あるときに一つ目は操作できるのですが二つ目が操作できていない状態です。
デバックモードで確認したところ `options` が２回目呼ばれるときにはからになっています

https://forms.gle/E84ii1SkAUY8631b7

[image: GoogleFromの例]

Comment: options = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("exportSelectPopup") のところを element -> elements にしてみたらどうなりますか？elementsに変えることで，そのページ内の複数のクラス (今回でいうclass="exportSelectPopup") をリストで取得することができます．

Comment: ありがとうございます
elementsにしたところプルダウンの内容をすべて(例の場合ですと３つ)分取得できました。
確認してみたところ `elements`に変更して取得した場合プルダウンの位置に対応した位置のプルダウンの内容が取得できるようです。
```     options=self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("exportSelectPopup")
        contents = options[?].find_elements_by_tag_name('content')
```
上記の?の位置に対応するプルダウンの位置を0始まりで渡せば(任意項目２を使いたければ `1` )うまく動かすことができそうです取り急ぎ確認結果をコードを修正してうまくいったら改めてどうしたかを記載しようかと思います

Comment: 以下のように対応することができましたありがとうございました。

```
        self.webElementClickOverlay(buttonInfo)
        time.sleep(3)
        options=self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("exportSelectPopup")
        contents = options[pullDownPosition].find_elements_by_tag_name('content')
        [i.click() for i in contents if i.text == target]
```

`pullDownPosition` はプルダウンの位置を０始まりで設定することで期待した通りに動きました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

上記 champon さんからのコメントをもとに解決できたのでそのコードを記載します

```
　　　self.webElementClickOverlay(buttonInfo) 
　　　　time.sleep(3) 
　　　　options=self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("exportSelectPopup") 
　　　　contents = options[pullDownPosition].find_elements_by_tag_name('content') 
　　　　[i.click() for i in contents if i.text == target]
```

pullDownPosition はプルダウンの位置を0始まりで設定することで期待した通りに動きました 。